# Why is my program not continuing after the first 10 Palindromic numbers? And also Why is my isPrime method not returning false for the number 4?

Tags: java, primes, palindrome

I'm not sure why my `ct` is not going all the way to 100 even though I clearly set it to go until it reaches 100.

```
public class PalindromicPrime
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {     


        int ct = 0;
          while(ct < 100)
          {
             if(isPalindrome(ct) && isPrime(ct))
             {
                if(ct % 10 != 0)
                {
                   System.out.print(ct + " ");
                }
                else
                {
                   System.out.print("\n");
                }
             }
             ct++;
          }
       public static boolean isPalindrome(int p) 
       {
          int palindrome = p;
          int reverse = 0;
          while (palindrome != 0) 
          {
             int remainder = palindrome % 10;
             reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
             palindrome = palindrome / 10;
          }
          if (p == reverse) 
          {
             return true;
          }
            return false;
       }
```

I'm assuming my `isPrime` code is wrong since I'm getting a 4 in my output. What's wrong with this method?

```
       public static boolean isPrime(int p)
       {
          for(int i = 2; i < p/2; i++)
          {
             if(p % i == 0)
             {
                return false;
             }
          }
          return true;
       }

}
```

Comment: `i * i <= p` (not `i < p/2`)

Answer (score 1):

First change you should do in your method `isPrime()` is change this line

```
for(int i = 2; i < p/2; i++)
```

to

```
for(int i = 2; i <= p/2; i++) // you can easily find the reason why it is necessary(=)
```

And also **you are printing palindromic numbers less than 100 which are prime,not first 100 palindrome numbers,** if you want to print first 100 palindrome numbers you can take another counter which will keep track of the numbers printed.

You can modify your main method like this:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
   {     
        int ct = 0,n=0; // n to count numbers printed/found
          while(n < 100) // change the condition to check n<100
          {
             if(isPalindrome(ct) && isPrime(ct))
             {
                System.out.print(ct + " ");
                if(n % 10 == 0)
                {
                   System.out.println();
                }
                n++; // incementing n after a number is found!
             }
             ct++;
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your isPrime function to following (replace `<` with `<=` as 4/2 is 2 and loop will not run at all for p=4):

```
public static boolean isPrime(int p) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= p / 2; i++) {
        if (p % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int ct = 2;
    int count = -1;
    while (count < 99) {
        if (isPalindrome(ct) && isPrime(ct)) {
            count++;
            if (count % 10 == 0) {
                System.out.print("\n" );
            }   
                System.out.print(ct + " ");
        }
        ct++;
    }
}
```

The only numbers that are palindrome and prime and less than 100 are:

```
1 2 3 5 7 11
```

Try changing the value of 100 to 102. Then you get the following output as 101 is the next palindromic prime after 11:

```
1 2 3 5 7 11 101
```

Comment: the goal of my problem is to print out the first 100 palindromic numbers. I assumed using the ct in the main method and setting equal to less than 100 would give me that. How would i set that paramter to not sto until i get 100 palindromic numbers?

Comment: when i run the code, it gives me only 7 values in the first line (up to 131) and then the next 8 lines are 10 digits each, and the last line is only one value. I should have clarified. I need to make each line only hold 10 numbers and then skip to next line. Sorry for confusion!

Comment: i made a small change to main. it is just a display issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your palindrome method is fine. It's your isPrime method that's not working because to check if a number is prime, you're supposed to test factors up to the square root of the number. So a simple change in the condition should do it,

```
public static boolean isPrime(int p)
       {
          for(int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(p); i++)
          {
             if(p % i == 0)
             {
                return false;
             }
          }
          return true;
       }

}
```